# How can i create .setTicker in my notifications bar

Tags: android, statusbar, batterylevel

My notifications bar is structure in this way:

```
             Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.full,+level+"%",System.currentTimeMillis());

             notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

             Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class); 

             PendingIntent penInt = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0 , i , 0);

             notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "Batteria al"+" "+level+"%", "Clicca per aprire l'applicazione", penInt);

             notifi.notify(215,notification);

        }
```

But i don't know how set the .setTicker with this structure. How can i do it? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.full,+level+"%",System.currentTimeMillis());
```

In this line the second parameter is the ticker text. you dont need to set it using other method.

btw this constructor is deprecated. Use [Notification.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html) instead

By using that

```
 Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(mContext)
         .setContentTitle("New mail from " + sender.toString())
         .setContentText(subject)
         .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_mail)
         .setLargeIcon(aBitmap)
         .setTicker(tickerText)
         .build();
```

Comment: ok thanks.. But i can't show the `.setTicker(+level+"%")`.. I can see only the icon.. Why? I mean, when i open the application the notification starts and i can see the icon and the setTricker. But later i see only the icon on top (and not the battery level). Do you understand what i mean?

Comment: Oh ok i understand, so the tricker will be shown only when the notification occours right? And how can i see the level in the notifications bar in place of the icon?

Comment: see the second example.. there is a title and a content.. :)

Comment: I mean, i want that the trickerText stay and don't disappear. :)But i don't know if is possible

Comment: AFAIK there is no such option .. but you can check further